# Content in a full-screen ZStack not centering as expected

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-zstack

Consider the following (in a landscape-only app):

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.9)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    .background(.gray)
}
```

}

Which results in this:
[image]

Why is the rectangle not centered? Why is there more space on the right than on the left? Happens on a device too.

Comment: Adding a border to the `ZStack` shows that  there are some space on the right that is not occupied by the `ZStack`. *Why* are you doing layout with `UIScreen` bounds anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting one. If you change the scaling factor from 0.9 to 0.8 then the blue area is centered perfectly. But when you set a frame size that needs to use the safe areas to fit, the position is not centered.

I did some measurements of the screen size of an iPhone 15 in landscape mode (which is what you appear to be using in your screenshot):

- the full screen size is 852 x 393
- there are leading and trailing safe areas of 59
- there is a bottom safe area of 21 (for the home bar)
- the central part within the safe areas is therefore 734 x 372.

The sizes delivered by the (deprecated) `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` are the full screen sizes. So when a factor of 0.9 is applied, the size of the blue area is being fixed at 766.8 x 353.7. This fits within the available height (of 372), but not within the available width (of 734). The excess width is 32.8 pt.

It is perhaps useful to note that the gray background is giving the impression that the `ZStack` is filling the screen, but this is not the case. You have applied the background using `.background(.gray)`, which ignores safe areas by default - see
[background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)). If you change it to `.background { Color.gray }` then safe areas are not ignored and the background shows you the exact size and position of the `ZStack`. The result is quite interesting:

[image: Screenshot]

What we see is:

- The frame of the `ZStack` is still observing the safe areas as far as possible.
- The width of the `ZStack` exactly matches the width of the blue area, because the blue content is forcing it to be wider than the area within the safe insets. So the `ZStack` has expanded into both the leading and trailing safe areas by half the excess width or 16.4 pt on both sides.
- The blue content slightly overlaps the bottom edge of the `ZStack`. This content is being vertically centered within the full screen height, so the gap to the bottom of the screen is (393 - 353.7) / 2 = 19.65. This is slightly less than the bottom safe inset of 21.
- Most interesting of all is the horizontal offset of the blue rectangle. Since it doesn't fit within the safe width, it needs to extend into the safe areas by 32.8 pt. **The surprise is that it only extends into the leading safe area!** So the gap on the leading side is (59 - 32.8) = 26.2. On the trailing side, the gap is still 59.

I think that what is happening is that the `ZStack` is calculating the horizontal offset for the content based on the assumption that the `ZStack` is in its default position. So the relative offset is half the excess width or 16.4 pt. But since the `ZStack` itself is already displaced by this much, it means the blue content has a double displacement. The result is that the correction for the excess width is fully applied on the leading side and the gap on the trailing side is the default safe area inset.

#### Workarounds

**1. Only ignore safe areas on the top and bottom edges**

```swift
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.9)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.top, .bottom]) // <- HERE
.background(.gray)
```

The effect of this change is to stop the `ZStack` from applying an offset to the content, so the horizontal position of the `ZStack` becomes the horizontal position of the content too (they are horizontally aligned and also horizontally centered).

This workaround is based on the assumption that the leading and trailing safe area insets are always matched. However, this might not be the case on all devices.

**2. Apply maximum size to the `ZStack` *again*  after the modifier `.ignoresSafeArea`**

```swift
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.9)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.ignoresSafeArea()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // ADDED
.background(.gray)
```

The first frame modifier on the `ZStack` extends the `ZStack` up to the safe areas. After ignoring safe areas, the second frame modifier extends the `ZStack` to the screen size.

**3. Apply max size and `ignoresSafeArea` to the blue rectangle**

```swift
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.9)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // ADDED
        .ignoresSafeArea() // ADDED
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
.background(.gray)
```

A frame with max size no longer needs to be set on the `ZStack`, because its size is dictated by the content. But the `ZStack` still needs to ignore safe areas.

**4. Use a `GeometryReader` as the parent container**

Using a `GeometryReader` is a better way of getting the screen size (because `UIScreen.main` is deprecated and it doesn't work properly with split screen on iPad). If the modifier `.ignoresSafeArea` is moved from the `ZStack` to the `GeometryReader` then the `ZStack` extends to the full screen size when the frame with max size is applied:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.9, height: proxy.size.height * 0.9)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.gray)
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

I would suggest, this is the best workaround.

All workarounds give the same result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Answer completely revised

Comment: Great insights! Thanks.